# Raphael JS transform scaling - rounded rectangle

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have a rounded rectangle element but whenever I try to scale it using transform it disappears of the page - but I don't understand why (it works fine if I remove the corner radius variable - so it is a standard rectangle)

```
var shape=paper.rect(200, 300, 150, 100, '5');
var newelement=shape.clone();
newelement.transform("s0.8");
```

Can anyone help? Or is this a bug with the library?

Comment: found the problem - my '5' should be just 5 (not a string!)

Comment: I'm surprised that choked up the library like that!  Raphael should feel a little ashamed right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the problem - my '5' should be just 5 (not a string!)